# wait for bullmq jobs and remove them on finish / fail

Tags: typescript, bullmq

i am trying to find a way to wait for a buch of bullmq jobs and then when finished remove them.
currently i do something like this:

```
const queues : Job[] = []
while (distance <= highZ + 1) {
    queues.push( await extruderJobque.add(
        `${distance}`,
        {
            folder, polygonFile, distance, skipMesh, weightsFile
        },
        {
            removeOnComplete: true,
            removeOnFail: true,
        }
    ))
    
    distance++
}

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    extrudeWorker.on('completed', async job => {

        console.log('EXTRUSION JOB COMPLETED')

        if (queues.map((id ) => id.id).includes(job.id)) {
       
            const index = queues.map((id ) => id.id).indexOf(job.id);
            await queues[index].remove()
            queues.splice(index, 1);
            console.log(`Removed job ${job.id} from queue`);
            console.log("queue length: ", queues.length)
        }
        if (queues.length === 0){
            resolve("")
        }
    
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(job.returnvalue))
    })
    extrudeWorker.on('failed', async job => {
        console.log('JOB FAILED')
        reject("")
    })


})
```

the problem is, that

1. does work if i have a concurrency of 1. when i have more then one process then it does not finish.
   and 2. when i run the algorithm 2 times, on "completed" returns also the old jobs. so first run it runs into on "completed" x times, when i run it again, it goes here x + 1 times and so on.

waht am i doing wrong here and how can i wait for the jobs?

thanks a lot!!

Cheers

Comment: I can see you added `removeOnComplete` and `removeOnFail` options. That should be enough, try removing that promise with completed and failed events handlers